# Pygame image loading not working why

Tags: pygame

This is my code below and it for some reason isn't working at all. I have the file in the same directory and everything. Im on a mac and I have no idea why this is not working. I would really like some help :D

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
gamedisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("test")
img = pygame.image.load('evilSquare.bmp')
imgx = 100
imgy = 100
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
while True:
    gamedisplay.blit(img, (100,100))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()


    pygame.display.update
```

Comment: Last line, do you want pygame.display.update() instead?

Comment: Check for error messages, as mentioned looks like you forgot the `()` in `update`.

Comment: Wow thanks @EliasBenevedes I am such an idiot for not realizing that lol

Comment: @somebodyy Does doing that solve your problem? If so we can close this question as a *"Simple Typographical Error"*.

Comment: I had another error when I had a thing for when you press the right arrow key imgx moves up 10 but it produced a ton of 1s behind it...

Comment: @somebodyy That can be solved by adding "gamedisplay.fill(255,255,255)" at the beginning of the while True loop. This will fill the screen with white before drawing everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the answers from the comments. I do not dare say the idea was mine here. As mentioned by @Elias Benevedes, you forgot the () in your last line. It should look like:

```
pygame.display.flip()
```

instead of:

```
pygame.display.flip
```

As said by @Elias Benevedes again, your problem listed in your comment can be solved using:

```
gamesdisplay.fill(white)
```

I hope these comments/answers/tips help you!